# PHP bindParam not working - blindValue is not the solution

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I can't figure this out.  I've googled it and a lot of answers refer to blindValue as the solution but I've also tried that with no luck.

The problem is that the SELECT statement is returning zero records but it should return one record.  If I hard code the values into the SQL statement it works but passing them in as parameters isn't.  Can some one please help me out with this?  Thanks.

```
<?php
function checklogin($email, $password){
    try
    {
        // Connection
        $conn;
        include_once('connect.php');
        // Build Query
        $sql = 'SELECT pkUserID, Email, Password, fkUserGroupID FROM tbluser WHERE Email = :email AND Password = :password';
        // $sql = 'SELECT pkUserID, Email, Password, fkUserGroupID FROM tbluser WHERE Email = "a" AND Password = "a"';
        // Prepare the SQL statement.
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        // Add the value to the SQL statement
        $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        // Execute SQL
        $stmt->execute();
        // Get the data in the result object
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll(); // $result is NULL always...

        // echo $stmt->rowCount(); // rowCount is always ZERO....

        // Check that we have some data
        if ($result != null)
        {
            // Start session
            if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
                session_start();
            }
            // Search the results
            foreach($result as $row){
                // Set global environment variables with the key fields required
                $_SESSION['UserID'] = $row['pkUserID'];
                $_SESSION['Email'] =  $row['Email'];
            }
            echo 'yippee';
            // Return empty string
            return '';
        }
        else {
            // Failed login
            return 'Login unsuccessful!';
        }
        $conn = null;
    }
    catch (PDOexception $e)
    {
        return 'Login failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
?>
```

the connect code is;

```
<?php
$servername = 'localhost';
$username = 'admin';
$password = 'password';

try {
    // Change this line to connect to different database
    // Also enable the extension in the php.ini for new database engine.
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database', $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    // echo 'Connected successfully';
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

I'm connecting to mySQL.  Thanks for the help,
Jim

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and never store passwords as plain-text.

Comment: @tadman Thanks for the advise, the code is at a very early stage - just having issues with the bindParam feature which is driving me crazy.

Comment: I understand, which is why I'm saying to be extra careful. It's easy to forget these things and create a nightmare scenario for yourself. That's why I'd strongly recommend cutting your teeth on a framework that fits your style and needs as this is a solved problem and you can focus on making your actual application instead of being bogged down in technical details.

Comment: Does this query work independent of PHP? Can you verify that the two variables you're binding are correct and don't include things like stray spaces? You can test by replacing `$email` with a string, for example.

Comment: Just for check try this: $sql = 'SELECT pkUserID, Email, Password, fkUserGroupID FROM tbluser WHERE Email = '.$email.' AND Password = '.$password;        I think your error is in functions params

Comment: This code is not real. Empty fetchAll's result is an empty array, not null

Comment: @Gerardo I have tried $sql = 'SELECT pkUserID, Email, Password, fkUserGroupID FROM tbluser WHERE Email = "a" AND Password = "a"'; and that worked.  I'll try your way later on but I don't think the query is the issue.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Thanks but when I use the RowCount its always zero so I'm trying to figure out why there is no records being returned.

Answer (score 0):

It was a simple but stupid error.

I had a variable called $password also in the connect.php file which was overwriting the $password that I was passing to the checklogin.

Jim